Proof of the Single Value Decomposition
I am working through the a proof of the single-value decomposition, from Strang's 'Introduction to Linear Algebra, 4th edition'. I have included the proof as shown in the book at the end of this post.
I have restated the proof in a slightly different way, that to me is much clearer. It would be great if someone could confirm this is a valid proof, as I am worried I have missed a logical step and am not so familiar with formally stating proofs.
We want to find
$$
A\pmb{v_i} = \sigma_i \pmb{u_i}
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \text{x} n}$, and $\pmb{v_i}$ are orthnormal and $\pmb{u_i}$ are orthonormal.
First, let's choose $\pmb{v}$ as the eigenvectors of $A^TA$. This is a free choice, and we know it will produce a set of orthonormal vectors. Therefore
\begin{gather*}
    (A^TA)\pmb{v} = \lambda \pmb{v}
\end{gather*}
We see for these $\pmb{v}$, then $A\pmb{v}$ will be eigenvectors of $AA^T$:
\begin{gather*}
    (A^TA)\pmb{v} = \lambda \pmb{v} \\[4pt]
    (AA^T)(A\pmb{v}) = \lambda (A\pmb{v})
\end{gather*}
So, we know that if we choose $\pmb{v}$ as an eigenvector of $A^TA$ then $A\pmb{v}$ will be an eigenvector of $AA^T$. But we want $\pmb{u}$ to be a set of orthonormal vectors, so we need to scale to length 1. We can find the length of $A\pmb{v}$:
\begin{gather*}
    (A^TA)\pmb{v} = \lambda \pmb{v} \\[4pt]
    \pmb{v} ^TA^TA\pmb{v} = \lambda \pmb{v}^T \pmb{v} \\[4pt]
    (A\pmb{v})^T(A\pmb{v}) = \lambda ||\pmb{v}||^2 \\[4pt]
    ||A\pmb{v}||^2 = \lambda ||\pmb{v}||^2 \\[4pt]
    ||A\pmb{v}|| = \sqrt{\lambda}||\pmb{v}||
\end{gather*}
We chose $\pmb{v}$ as length 1. Therefore to scale the length 1 eigenvector of $AA^T$ $\pmb{u}$ to $A\boldsymbol{v}$ we must multiply by $\sqrt{\lambda}$.
$$
A\pmb{v_i} = \sigma_i \pmb{u_i}
$$
When $\pmb{v_i}$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $A^TA$, then $\pmb{u_i}$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and $\sigma_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$.
As stated in the book:


The argument is fine, but it's missing some details.

First, let's choose $\pmb{v}$ as the eigenvectors of $A^TA$. This is a free choice, and we know it will produce a set of orthonormal vectors.

There is not "the" eigenvectors of a matrix. For each eigenvalue there is an eigenspace. What happens here is that because $A^TA$ is symmetric, eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. But you want way more than this, you want a basis of eigenvectors. And this requires more care (for instance, because eigenspaces may have dimension greater than one, and also because you have to show that you actually get a basis).

So, we know that if we choose $\pmb{v}$ as an eigenvector of $A^TA$ then $A\pmb{v}$ will be an eigenvector of $AA^T$.

Yes, if you show that $A\pmb v $ is nonzero whenever $\pmb v$ is an eigenvector for $A^TA$. This requires you to show that the kernels of $A$ and $A^TA$ are the same.

We chose $\pmb{v}$ as length 1. Therefore to scale the length 1 eigenvector of $AA^T$ $\pmb{u}$ to $A\boldsymbol{v}$ we must multiply by $\sqrt{\lambda}$.

You should be talking about $\pmb v_i$, $\pmb u_i$, and $\lambda_i$ here.
